# Elastic - Use Java High Level Rest Client To Perform a String Query

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I'm writing a service for our company, using Java, in order to make it easier for the users to query Elastic. For that mission I'm using "Java High Level REST Client".

Let's say I have a query that looks like this:

```
host='hostnameOne' AND (owner='Sam' OR cpuNum=5) OR type LIKE 'Ubuntu'
```

Is there a way to use QueryBuilder or anything similar in order to build this query easily? I saw there is something called 'simpleQueryStringQuery' but I failed while trying to convert the query above.

Comment: Did you check this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-query-builders.html

Answer (score 0):

The choices you have are below:

1. Use query_string, not recommended for user-generated input. It will not work exactly as you expect it to. Moreover, it could be dangerous if you do not disable certain special characters and keywords
2. Use  simple_query_string, it is the user-facing alternative to query_string. It doesn't support AND, OR, LIKE though. You will need to parse the input and transform it into the simple_query_string syntax
3. Use the new sql rest api. The example you provided seems like a WHERE clause of SQL command https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-rest.html .